# whats the problem with this ruby hash

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I was trying to create a hash and later on convert it into json object

```
 a = { "event": "game",
        "properties": 
            {
                "ip": "123.123.123.123",
                  "token": "dejdedjjjne",
                  "time": 1245613885,
                  "action": "play"
                }
        }
```

Getting an error:-

```
  : odd number list for Hash
  and syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ruby's syntax is to use `=>` instead of `:`.  In Ruby 1.9, you also have the option of retaining the colons if you omit the quotes around the keys (this also makes the key a symbol).

Comment: Thanks. I found this while trying to understand the call `link_to "Name", id: 1`. Thought it's some fancy JSON syntax trick ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use '=>' instead of ':' for a hash in ruby.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, a hash is like this: `{"key" => "value"}`, not with the colon. If you want to convert it to json, you could do something like this:

```
require 'json'
my_hash = {'key' => 'value'}
json_hash = my_hash.to_json
```